# Create a UIImage with a URL in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uiimage

To create an UiImage with a image file, I use the code as below:

```
UIImage *aImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"demo.jpg"]autorelease];
```

If I want to create an UiImage with the URL http://example.com/demo.jpg, how to do that?

Thanks

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: Might want to look at this project: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 153, accepted):

This is a three step process. First you will create an `NSURL` object to hold the URL we are attempting to access. We will supply this URL to the `NSData` class method, `+dataWithContentsOfURL:` to obtain the image over the network as raw data, then use the `+imageWithData:` class method on `UIImage` to convert the data into an image.

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/demo.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Please note that `+dataWithContentsOfURL:` executes a synchronous network request. If you run this on the main thread, it will block the UI until the image data is received from the network. Best practice is to run any network code on a background thread. If you're targeting OS 4.0+ you could do something like this...

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/demo.jpg"];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I got an error message while putting the code in a class, please see my UPDATE

Comment: Fixed the typo. There was an extra closing parenthesis in the first dispatch_async() call.

Comment: @MarkAdams I don't know why but this is inconsistently working for me. Sometimes imageData is nil with NSCocoaErrorDomain 256

Answer (score 7):

Here's what the same code might look like in Swift:

```
let image_url = NSURL("http://i.imgur.com/3yY2qdu.jpg")

let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    // do some task
    let image_data = NSData(contentsOfURL: image_url!)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // update some UI
        let image = UIImage(data: image_data!)
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: At Xcode 9, the preferred Swift syntax for async dispatch would be `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { //block }`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to load image from the web the following library may be helpful:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

It's a `UIImageView` category which handles async loading and image caching from url.