# how to save an online image in to iphone photo album

Tags: iphone

my application is an image base application.

there is an option for seach online.if  we press a button there is a webview controller and

goes to google home page.there we can search image.my requirement is select an image and save

in to photo album

how it is possible.

Regards

Baiju

Comment: you just try to long press that image I think save image action sheet appears you save that image try once.

Comment: ok try it if its work then inform us.

Answer (score 2):

Download the image into a UIImage:

[Create a UIImage with a URL in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694215/create-a-uiimage-with-a-url-in-ios)

Save the UIImage to the photo album:

[How to save picture to iPhone photo library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library)

Pretty easy to do those searches on Stack Overflow don't you think?