# Is there any way to pass a PFFile (image) to another controller and display it without querying the database in the new controller?

Tags: ios, parsing, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

This is a question I have asked over at Parse forums and I have not had any reply from them for the past 3 days. Hence I am posting here.

Hi,

I have a PFQueryTableViewController and the table has custom cells with images and different labels. This Table navigates to another DetailViewController on the selection of a row. The DetailViewController need to display an image in its view, which we acquire from our query to the Parse database in the PFQueryTableViewController. How do I achieve that ?

**TABLEVIEWCONTROLLER.M**

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@end

NSMutableArray* detailObjects;
DetObj* clickedObj;

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    // This method is called every time objects are loaded from Parse via the PFQuery

    for (PFObject* object in self.objects)
    {
        DetailObj* obj = [[DetailObj alloc ] init ];
        [obj setDetName:[object objectForKey:@"detName"]];
        [mov setDetImage:[object objectForKey:@"detImage"]];
        [detailObjects addObject:obj];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"upCell";

    customBigTableCell *cell = (customBigTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[customBigTableCell alloc] init];
    }

    cell.name.text = [object objectForKey:@"detName"];
    cell.image.file = [object objectForKey:@"detImage"];

    //this is essential for loading the image from the database
    [cell.image loadInBackground];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    newDetailController* newController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];

    clickedObj = [[DetObj alloc] init];

    NSIndexPath* path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    clickedObj = [detailObjects objectAtIndex:path.row];

    [newController setDetInfo:clickedObj];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
}
```

I have tried using a PFImageView as stated below in the DetailViewController. detailInfo is the object passed from the previous PFQueryTableViewController.

**newDetailController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    PFImageView* detImage = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,0,320,150)];

    PFFile* file = detailInfo.fullImage.file;

    detImage.file = file;

    [detImage loadInBackground];

    [self.view addSubview:detImage];

}
```

But I have this error.

`reason: '-[PFFile file]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I dont want to query the database again to get the info I have already obtained in the previous controller.

Thanks Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to a different approach and it works well for me. But Thanks Eddie for telling me about NSCache and its usage.

I store the URL of the PFFile associated with the object, and then pass the URL to the next controller. Then I display the image using the following code in `-(void)viewDidLoad()`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: imgURL];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI
        self.upImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
```

Thanks to this thread [Create UIIMAGE with URL in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694215/create-a-uiimage-with-a-url-in-ios)

Thanks again.
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Once you have obtained the PFFile In the PFQueryTableViewController you should save that image into an image cache. It can be stored in the filesystem or in memory. It's best to use NSCache if you put it in memory as it automatically frees up memory when needed. Then in your DetailViewController get the image. You can use the parseId as the image key.

To specifically answer your question, you cannot pass a PFFile as it is not guaranteed to stay in memory or storage. I believe it may actually execute in certain conditions but it is not guaranteed. Each time you need a PFFile, you should get a PFObject by the parseId, then download the PFFile. This counts as two requests. However, Parse is smart enough that it keeps its own cache -- but the lifetime is not specified and not guaranteed. The best thing to do is to use filesystem, memory, or core data to persist the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply eddie.... I will try and let you know how it goes. And also will update this as the answer, if this is the only way out.

Comment: @eddie.. sorry i thot i mentioned it earlier.. i have made an update in the below answer... Also i couldnt say that your answer was useful cos my rep is < 15 :( so sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this recently.

```
ParseTableViewController.m

//----- CREATE SUBVIEW HERE -----//
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
PFObject *passObj = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
HouseDataViewController *detailViewController = [[HouseDataViewController alloc] init];
[detailViewController setReceiveObj:passObj];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

DetailViewController.h

```
// include this to receive the object passed from the PFTableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *ReceiveObj;
```

and on the DetailViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
if (self.ReceiveObj){

// House Image
    PFImageView *houseView = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
    houseView.frame = CGRectMake(border, y, 280, 196);
    houseView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big_frame.png"];     // placeholder image
    houseView.file = (PFFile *)[detail objectForKey:@"house_picture"];
    //[houseView loadInBackground];
    [scrollView addSubview:houseView];
    [houseView loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // do code here
        } else {
            // ... error
        }
    }];

  }

}
```