# Modify UIImageview in Xcode using URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiimage, xcode7

I tired to use this code in Xcode to modify a picture but nothing change

```
    UIImage *myimage= (UIImage *)[tableView viewWithTag:tag+1];

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_c0deb2e1dd65_128.png"];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: imageURL];
        if ( data == nil ){
            return;

        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"dddddddd");

   __block myimage = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
        });

    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: why are u converting the uiview to uiimage ?

Comment: do you meant to use UIImageView ?

Comment: also where are you calling this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a UIImage with a URL in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694215/create-a-uiimage-with-a-url-in-ios)

Comment: You are likely confusing `UIImage` with `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
UIImageView *myImageView= (UIImageView *)[tableView viewWithTag:tag+1];

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: 
  @"https://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_c0deb2e1dd65_128.png"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^
{
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: imageURL];
    if ( data == nil )
    {
        return;
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        NSLog(@"dddddddd");

        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
        myImageView.image = myImage;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Duncan C