# I am getting error while getting image back firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase

[please check my image for storing and retrieving data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXpIj.png)[image]

I am getting an error because I want retrieve image from firebase, my url is string but error states about uiImage cannot be string, is there away I can get an image shown of my uiImageView.

By the Way this is my model view class  of user below
        class User {

```
    var username:String!
    var userage:String!
    var uid:String!
    var profileImageUrl: String!


    init (uid:String,dictionary:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) {

    self.uid = uid
    if let username = dictionary [ "userName" ] as? String{

        self.username = username
    }

    if let userage = dictionary [ "useAge" ] as? String {

        self.userage = userage
    }

   if let profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String

 {

      self.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl
   }


 }

    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but may I ask, what theme are you using? I like this, I may change mine

Comment: @George_E press command key and ,(comma) key. preferences I am using is dusk

Comment: Cheers! Used to use dark, now I have switched to this, but with grey comments :)

Comment: @George_E  #########yes

Answer (score 0):

If `user.profileImageURL` is actually an URL, you have to download the image and assign that to `self.swipeLabel.image`.

To download image from URL, Please refer this post: [Create a UIImage with a URL in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694215/create-a-uiimage-with-a-url-in-ios)

If the image is already stored, the use the following code.

```
self.swipeLabel.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: profileimageurl)
```

Comment: I have already stored the image infact it is the Download ur,l if you see  my model for user I put the url in my dictionary as the document stated , I think I am using story board may be that's why but still looking to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Akbar You are just setting `imageUrl` in `User` model so you still have to download the image from this `URL`. Follow the question referenced above to download the image.

Comment: @kamran I have attach an image above  on how I am storing and retrieving image I have tried above code it didn't work.

Comment: @Anand it didn't worked also can you fix my code review thanks

Comment: @Anand ["userAge": 22, "userName": haren]
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/haay-84d3f.appspot.com/o/userPicture%2FBD41FDD0-85EE-479B-80D0-9E1F758A4ED9?alt=media&token=30097c65-f41a-4a26-97e0-1b2282ed3755

Comment: Permission denied. Not able to see the values in the above link.

Comment: @Anand sorry no idea you mind checking I am storing and retrieving picture code is right above I have attached a new picture.(code) above